# Using an England bought PC ATX PSU, in Portugal

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Im in Portugal. Im going to buy a PSU for my PC on AmazonUK. Can i just re-use my old power cable from my old psu? Portugal and England have the same voltages and hz, the same electricity. Only the plugs differ.
Or do i need to use an adapter together with the cable that comes with the new psu?
Thank you.

Comment: Just use your old power cable. The new PSU may not even come with a power cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL, DR:

Yes, you can use your old cable.

---

## In detail:

#### Converters and adaptors:

These cables are adaptors. Adaptors, no matter if they have cables or not, are usually only mechanic, meaning that they just convert from plug A to plug B by having wires from e.g.:

- plug A (pin 1) to plug B (pin 1),
- plug A (pin 2) to plug B (pin 3), and
- plug A (pin 3) to plug B (pin 2),

or something like that.

Now of course one can convert from AC to DC or from 120 VAC (60 Hz) to 230 VAC (50Hz) (and vice versa), but that (especially the frequency conversion) would need some electrical components - basically you would need something at least the size of your USB-charger or your laptop's PSU-brick, and usually, such converters also state their input- and output-values.

**In a nutshell:**

Adaptors convert only mechanically (plug A to plug B), while converters also convert from voltage A to voltage B / AC to DC / ... .

---

#### Examples for mechanical conversion:

a USB-A to Micro-USB cable:

[image: USB-A to Micro-USB cable]

...or USB-A to Micro-USB without cable:

[image: USB-A to Micro-USB]

a UK-to-3prong cable:

[image: UK-to-3prong cable]

...or a UK-to-SchuKo-adaptor:

[image: UK-to-Schuko-converter]

---

#### "Get to the point, please: Can I use my equipment or not!?"

As these cables do not convert voltages/frequencies, you can easily replace them if the voltage/frequency in your country (or in your electircal outlet) are compatible with that of the equipment you want to power with it.

Usually, electrical equipment should somewhere state its input-requirements. If the equipment states something like "110~240 VAC", "115/230 V~", "100-250~ V" or any combination of that, [you can use it worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Voltages)(1). If it only states "120 VAC" or something like this, you cannot use it in Portugal, as Portugal uses 230 V. If it only states "240 V~" or something like this, you cannot use it in the USA, as the USA use 120 V. *Note: Usually, the specifications on these labels are a bit unprecise. So don't worry if the label says "220 V" - it will work.*

*(1) If you don't like tables, here's a graphic from [Wikipedia, showing which country uses which standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_frequency#Standardization)*:
[image: By Pawanexh Kohli at English Wikipedia, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=48792490]

---

## What you should  not(!)  do:

If there is no label on your eqipment and even Google can't help you finding the specifications, you could take an educated guess by:

1. Knowing the country where it was sold
2. Looking at its original connector and [finding out to which country it belongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Types_in_present_use).

However, **I strongly discourage using those two methods**, as you could be wrong, **leading at least to defective equipment**, but also the **risk of fire, injuries, and electrocution**.

<sub><del>Though I have to admit: I once accidentally did that with a scanner's PSU: It just made a short, hissing noise, and besides from that (and it being dead now), nothing happened...</del></sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. The part where you mentioned that cables are basicaly mechanical adaptors, that's what really put my mind at ease. Now i know for sure that i can just reuse my old cable. By the way the Psu is a Seasonic SSR-850PD: 100 -240v, 50 - 60Hz. Very good and ellaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse your old power cable from old PSU. You can even use PSU bought from UK in US because they have dedicated circuitry to accept various voltages in input.

[From corsairs website:](http://www.corsair.com/en-eu/cx-series-cx750-750-watt-80-plus-bronze-certified-atx-psu-na)

> Active PFC with full range AC input (100-240 VAC)

Comment: We don't know which PSU Vitor bought, so there's no guarantee that his PSU will have 100-240 VAC support.